# How can I read a netbsd (UFS filesystem) disk?

Tags: bsd

I tried installing netbsd on another computer as I wanted to learn some BSD-stuff. Now I want to mount the disk in Ubuntu 12.04, to be able to exchange files. But nothing I found on Google works. Any hints for me? I successfully mounted my Windows 7 partition. So at least i know a bit about how mount works.

Output of `sudo fdisk -l` shows `/dev/sde2 1547186176 2930274303 691544064 a9 NetBSD`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default BSD partitions are formatted with FFSv1, but there are other FS types like 4.4BSD, FFSv2 etc([source](http://netbsd.gw.com/cgi-bin/man-cgi?newfs+8+NetBSD-5.0.1+i386)). FFS is also called [UFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_File_System).

You can try mount the partition /dev/sde2 with `sudo mount -t ufs -o ro,ufstype=ufs2 /dev/sde2 /media/mountdir`(create the directory mountdir first)([source](http://ghantoos.org/2009/04/04/mounting-ufs-in-readwrite-under-linux/)).

Other `ufstype` options can be found [here](http://kerneltrap.org/node/3431).

Sadly, Linux only has read support ([source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_systems)) for UFS-based filesystems, as "..Compatibility between (UFS) implementations as a whole is spotty at best " ([source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_File_System)).

<sub>Consolidated from comment discussions. Credit where credit is due: Samik answered this</sub>